# Recording device resets to default after reboot

Tags: 20.04, sound, microphone

Attached to my Ubuntu 20.04 desktop, are two audio recording devices: a nice condenser microphone, and a shoddy webcam microphone. Every time I power cycle my desktop, Ubuntu defaults to the webcam microphone. Is there a way to change this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using the `pactl` command.

**First**: List the audio devices using

```
pactl list short sources
```

**Second**: To set a default output device run the command

```
pactl set-default-sink <'output_device_name'>
```

Example: `pactl set-default-sink 'alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo'`

Now that the device names are known, and they have been verified to work by using the pactl application. They can be used in conjunction with the default Pulse configuration file.

First, open the file `/etc/pulse/default.pa` using :

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/pulse/default.pa
```

Then scroll to the bottom of the file, where two lines starting with `set-` will be commented out.

Now, uncomment these lines and replace the words input and output with the number of the sink (for output) / source (for input) that you want to be the default.

```
### Make some devices default
set-default-sink 3
set-default-source 3
```

OR
You can also put the input/output name in /etc/pulse/default.pa instead of the input/output number.

```
### Make some devices default
set-default-sink alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo
set-default-source alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor
```

After doing this, delete the `~/.config/pulse` directory, and then reboot the system. Once the system comes back up, the appropriate devices should now be set as the defaults.

*The downside to this approach, will be that if the device list changes, the indexes of the devices may also change, meaning this process may need to be repeated; but it resolves the immediate issue, when there are multiple audio devices connected on a permanent basis.*

Comment: @Daniel Copley I would suggest renaming instead of deleting `mv ~/.config/pulse ~/.config/pulse.old` then reboot first... this might, alone, resolve the issue... If after that, it is still not resolved, then you can go ahead with modifying  `/etc/pulse/default.pa`.

Comment: @Raffa Yes, that can be done too. Anyways, it gets regenerated after reboot.